# VSCode doesn't open in the right directory in WSL

Tags: linux, terminal, git, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL, specifically the `WLinux Distro`. I have installed everything. NodeJS, Git, zsh, oh-my-zsh, even solved my problem with the SSH Keys somehow.

But, now when I move to the desired directory in WSL and execute `Code .`, VSCode opens, but in the entirely wrong place. I see my System32 files open in VSCode, and I cannot navigate with the integrated terminal. I have these settings.

```
{
    "terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe"
}
```

With the above settings, I can see zsh, activated in the Integrated terminal, but open in system32. I need this opened in my working file.

**The Question:**
**Please, can you tell me how to make, 1) VSCode to open by typing `Code .`, in WSL terminal, and how to set the integrated terminal to be the same as WSL. Also, if you could explain to me why it would be great. I am losing this WSL System at some point. Thanks**

In WSL Terminal if I do regular `code .` without Capital it spits out this.

````
projectName git:(master) code .                                                                               zsh: no such file or directory: /mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe ```

Git seems to work in WSL Terminal since I can do `glog`.
````

Comment: I even tried something as simple as that, `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "wsl.exe"`, and still doesn't work. It still open up in System32.. I have read various answers, but nothing works. And the more engineered ones, I don't understand.

Comment: Also, both VSCode and the files I am trying to open are on WSL. I also installed VSCode on Windows, but it didn't solve anything.

Comment: Also, another thing. If I do Code filename, inside my project it justs opens it as blank. And the terminal is unusable until I close VSCode.

Answer (score 3):

For Zsh and working, do not call wsl.exe but the distrib. I use Ubuntu 1804 and my settings are :

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "ubuntu1804.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["run"],
```

The shell is in the windows path, so write the fullpath is useless.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the debian shell from the windows store and this config works for me:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\debian.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["run"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved what you are describing by following this guide:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

It requires using Visual Studio Code Insiders along with the Remote Development extension.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Well not much point now since my answer that actually works is down voted.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu, i use:

Press `ctrl + ,` to open

```
settings.json
```

paste this at the bottom

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Users\\U=USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\ubuntu.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["run"],
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "fira code"
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers didn't work for me so anyone else wondering, you can change the WSL starting directory using the --cd flag.  I altered my WSL terminal instance settings to provide that flag.

Here's my settings from settings.json on VSCode:

```
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "cme": {
      "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
      "args": [
        "-d",
        "cmeUbuntu",       //CHANGE THIS TO YOUR WSL INSTALLATION NAME
        "--cd",
        "~"                //PUT YOUR PATH HERE
      ],
      "cwd": "c:\\"
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "cme"
```

If you follow the following section on the Visual Studio Microsoft site you will see these steps in detail:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles

[pic of terminal drop down from vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V2nO.png)

Comment: How is this answering the question?

Comment: You set your working directory in the settings.json on the //PUT YOUR PATH HERE part, this will then open your WSL instance on the right directory.